# Is there an accepted Coding Style for multiple ES6 Arrow Functions?

Tags: javascript, functions, lambda, es6

I'm starting to use ES6 arrow functions more, but haven't found a coding style that I like, especially when chaining them together.  e.g., [Eric Elliott gives this code](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/familiarity-bias-is-holding-you-back-its-time-to-embrace-arrow-functions-3d37e1a9bb75):

`mix = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), x)`

And touts how ES6 lets you write it all on "one line of code", but that's partly due to formatting standards, which would require that the `function(x) {...}` alternative version to have the { and } on separate lines, etc...

Is there a "coding style standard" (or more likely several) for how that line should be formatted, particularly with newlines?

In my limited research, the [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-functions-arrow-functions) and [Mozilla Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are silent.

Comment: IMHO such "one liners" should be avoided since they are not particularly readable ...I'm probably one of the many biased. I just hope I'll never have to maintain his code.

Comment: @dagnelies - largely agree with you, that code is an extreme example.  But I wonder if better formatting would make it more readable / maintainable.

Comment: The common name for what you're producing with that line of code is a "Curried function", which may help in searching for existing style guides that mention them.  It also turns up [this article](http://2ality.com/2017/11/currying-in-js.html) which gives a rationale for avoiding them entirely.

Comment: Something is wrong when it makes me wish it was written in lisp.

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#arrow-functions

Comment: My main problem with that as a "one liner" is the `=>` inside the reduce is not associated with either of the other two `=>`s. Spliting that out into `const call = (arg, fn) => fn(arg); const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce(call, x)` is much more palatable.

Comment: I found this link to be a good point of reference: https://github.com/standard/standard/blob/b6919b47573ec6940eb8eee36d8d16969ff46103/RULES.md